# How to show logo and title in single line?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress-theming

I extended my theme from twentyfourteen. And I have this header php now:

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
    <div class="header-main">
        <img class="site-logo" src="<?php echo bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/images/ic_logo.png" alt="Image" width="32" height="32"/>
        <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>

        <div class="search-toggle">
            <a href="#search-container" class="screen-reader-text" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="search-container"><?php _e( 'Search', 'twentyfourteen' ); ?></a>
        </div>

        <nav id="primary-navigation" class="site-navigation primary-navigation" role="navigation">
            <button class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Primary Menu', 'twentyfourteen' ); ?></button>
            <a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentyfourteen' ); ?></a>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu', 'menu_id' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div id="search-container" class="search-box-wrapper hide">
        <div class="search-box">
            <?php get_search_form(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

And CSS class for logo image:

```
.site-logo {
    float: left;
}
```

Base theme CSS styles:

```
.site-title {
    float: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 48px;
    margin: 0;

    /* Nav-toggle width + search-toggle width - gutter = 86px */
    max-width: -webkit-calc(100% - 86px);
    max-width:         calc(100% - 86px);
}

.site-title a,
.site-title a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

But logotype shows above site name...

How I can align it into single string?

Comment: which is `logotype`?

Comment: This `<img class="site-logo" src="<?php echo bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/images/ic_logo.png" alt="Image" width="32" height="32"/>` in my theme folder.

Comment: so you want the `h1` and the image / logo one one line?

Comment: Yeah, I need to show logo and after text (site name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS property you need to understand here is the `display` property. The `img` tag has a display value of `inline-block`, so it has a width and height and will display on the same line. However, the `h1` tag has a display value of `block`. Block level elements essentially put a line break before and after themselves, making them display on their own line.

You can overcome this behaviour by either making the `h1` an `inline` or `inline-block` element:

```
h1 { display: inline-block; }
```

Or by using the `float` property to overcome this behaviour. This will be a little bit more tricky for a newcomer to get their head around. [W3Schools provide this article](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp), which you may find useful.

Comment: I try it but nothing changed. `.site-title {
 font-size: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.site-logo {
 float: left;
 display: inline-block;
}`

Comment: It's base theme style: `.site-title {
 float: left;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 700;
 line-height: 48px;
 margin: 0;

 /* Nav-toggle width + search-toggle width - gutter = 86px */
 max-width: -webkit-calc(100% - 86px);
 max-width:         calc(100% - 86px);
}

.site-title a,
.site-title a:hover {
 color: #fff;
 display: block;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 white-space: nowrap;
}`

Comment: I think trying to solve this has led to you putting layer upon layer of conflicting CSS. If it was me, I would remove everything to do with float and width and start again, with just a simple `display:inline-block;` declaration for the `h1`.

Comment: You're right! I changed h1 by span and define custom style without overriding and all work! :) Thanks!